# How do I add a Reddit function to my Python Discord Bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, reddit

I want to make a bot that when you do "!meme it posts a random meme from r/memes/hot/. How would I do that? I already have some base code, but it doesn't work. Also, I'm not sure what exactly is a user_agent is. could someone give me an example?

```
client = Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='id',
                     client_secret='secret',
                     user_agent='windows 10: Meme Scraper (by /u/PotatoLord1207)')

@client.command()
async def meme():
    memes_submissions = reddit.subreddit('memes').hot()
    post_to_pick = random.randint(1, 20)
    for i in range(0, post_to_pick):
        submission = next(x for x in memes_submissions if not x.stickied)

    await bot.say(submission.url)
```

Comment: That should be `client.say`, not `bot.say`.  Are you actually running your bot?  `client.run("token")`

Comment: i fixed that problem, but it still won't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: What does "won't work" mean?

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/468191281357651979/513524132990943234/reeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.PNG

Comment: thats the error. I'm pretty new to discord.py so the error doesn't make much sense to me

Comment: A 401 error means "Unauthorized".  Your reddit account doesn't have the permissions it needs to complete that action.

Comment: How could i get the permissons?

Comment: I don't know.  It may also mean that you're logging in with incorrect credentials.  You may want to try logging in with intentionally incorrect credentials and see if you get a different error.

Comment: Make sure your app is setup correctly in reddit. See here: https://i.imgur.com/RSe1imt.png. Make sure yours is similar.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a meme command in discord.py rewrite version. This may help you:

```
@client.command()
async def meme(ctx):
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit("memes")
    all_subs = []

    top = subreddit.top(limit = 50)

    for submission in top:
        all_subs.append(submission)

    random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)

    name = random_sub.title
    url = random_sub.url

    embed = discord.Embed(title = name, color=discord.Color.gold())
    embed.set_image(url = url)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"Asked by {ctx.author.name}")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```